# Laravel Error with str.php in vendor directory

Tags: php, laravel

For some reason I started getting this error after a few days. I didn't change anything from the time my Laravel application was working to the time it threw this parse error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_USE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /home/fzystudi/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php on line 7
```

[Here](http://www.fzystudio.com/public/) is the site live with error.

Here is what I tried for solving the errors:

- I wiped everything clean and installed laravel again. Same error. So I then did composer update. Still no change. I did composer update again and still no change.
- I also downloaded the developer version and stable version. Still no difference.
- I cloned the exact file from str.php and the file is the same on github as it is in my app on my ftp server.
- I uploaded to hostgator and A2 hosting. Same error on both sites.
- [Here](http://laravel.io/forum/04-18-2014-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-use-expecting-t-function) is the thread on the laravel forum I posted. No one has been able to help yet.

What seems to be the cause and what is the fix?

This is my controller:

```
<?php

class SiteController extends BaseController {

public function __construct() {
    //parent::__construct();
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
}
//homepage for our store
public function getIndex() {
    return View::make('site.index');

}
}
```

My composer.json:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "laravel/laravel": "4.1.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Comment: When this error happens ? What code you have written on which controller or model ?

Comment: This is my controller:

Comment: Try deleting your `vendor` directory and re-running `composer install`.  That is a syntax error in the Laravel framework, so if you haven't touched that (which you shouldn't) then its not your error.

Comment: Just follow the instruction given by the `Sam`.

Comment: Good advice, but I already deleted the vendor file twice and re-installed twice with composer from scratch. After I ran composer with a new vendor directory and dependencies I uploaded that directory manully by ftp to my online host A2.

Comment: Also, why would someone down vote this legitimate question?

Comment: Maybe someone did it because you didn't posted any code and refered to another site.

Comment: You didn't tell when the error happens, on which route ? BTW, Make sure you have `PHP >= 5.3.7` installed on your server. If you run/ssh `php -v` you'll get the version is being used.

Comment: I am running php 5.3.8

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you're getting the bleeding edge version of Laravel which has started to make use of traits. I'm assuming line 7 of the `Str.php` file in your `vendor` directory is something like this?

```
use MacroableTrait;
```

You should check your `composer.json` file to make sure you're depending on the stable release of Laravel 4.1.

```
"laravel/laravel": "4.1.*"
```

You may need to delete your `vendor` directory again as well as the `composer.lock` file. If you don't remove the lock file you'll just re-install the same dependencies again. Once installed you can check the version you have by running `artisan --version` from your command line in the installed directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jason. I though I found my problem by cloning the wrong depository. I was cloning laravel/framework instead of laravel/laravel. I now have the stable version but also have the same error. I have done everything I can possibly think of. Here is my composer.json script above in original post.